# JQuery Scrollable Text

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'm searching for a jquery plugin that will bound text inside a scrollable box. Most of the scroll plugins are converting the browser scroll bar but I want to keep that as it is and usuable. This is just to contain a large amount of text in a small space.

It's like this [page](http://www.class.pm/files/jquery/uscrollbar/demo/) where at the very bottom they are containing a large amount of text in a small scrollable box. I tried to implement this plugin but I'm kinda new to JQuery so the meager instructions weren't enough for me to get off my feet. If I can use this plugin to do what I want, is this code right?:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".Information").uscrollbar();
});
</script>

<div id="Hotel" class="Information">
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: You don't need the e in $(document).ready(function(e)

Answer (score 3):

You really don't need jQuery for this. Just some CSS.

```
.Information{
height:100px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

If you have a genuine need for this plugin then make sure you're referencing jQuery correctly and the link to the plugin js file.

If you run the page in your browser do you get anything in the console window. Any errors.

EDIT: Added a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35zXU/2/)

EDIT: Also be sure you're referencing the required assets:

```
jquery.uscrollbar.js
jquery.uscrollbar.css
```

Comment: yes but I would like to customize the scrollbar of the box to something nicer, is that still possible with only css?

Comment: @Richard, then you should clarify that in the original question.

Comment: You can't really customize the scrollbar with css (limited) so this plugin might meet that need better.

Comment: @DaveHogan which is where i'm getting stuck...i dont really understand how to customize it. There isn't a height property or anything like that. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you trying to customize exactly? Is it currently working and you need help customizing it?

Comment: @DaveHogan I guess i don't need to customize. But it won't work in the first place. When I run the page, I just see the text. There is now box or scroll bar for that matter.

Comment: I've added a JsFiddle to my answer to show it working without that plugin.

Comment: @DaveHogan yah but i'm talking about the plugin not working. I don't want the standard scroll bar, i want it to look like the one in the demo. Which is why i'm trying to use the plugin

Comment: Ok - but you said before that "I guess i don't need to customize". Never mind - I've updated the jsfiddle to show the plug in working

Comment: @DaveHogan is that the correct link? I just see scroll box using css and no plugin.

Comment: yes: http://jsfiddle.net/35zXU/2/ - the assets are loaded under Manage Resources (2)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to dynamically do this to elements, just wrap the content in a `<div>` with a special class:

**CSS**:

```
.scroll {
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.elements_that_should_scroll').wrap($('<div>', {'class': 'scroll'}));
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nW7uH/**

If not, just give those elements the class `scroll` and it should work just fine without JS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify a fixed width and height for your container div, in your case, the div with the class Information. Add this to your CSS file.

```
.Information {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
```