# JQuery Plugin not showing correctly

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, scroll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery Scrollable Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503389/jquery-scrollable-text)

I'm trying to use [this](http://www.class.pm/files/jquery/uscrollbar/demo/) plugin and here's my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".Information").uscrollbar();
});
</script>

<div id="Hotel" class="Information">
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
    </div>
```

But when I open up the page, it just shows the text but there's no box containing the text or a scroll bar like shown in the demo picture. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you asked this question 30 minutes ago

Comment: Did you include the .js file for the plugin

Comment: In my answer on your previous question  I believe your not referencing the .css file. I have a jsfiddle with your code working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height of the div to 50px and then try again..

```
.Information
 {
    height: 50px;
 }    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $(".Information").uscrollbar();
    });
    </script>

<div id="Hotel" class="Information">
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
        <p>blah</p>
    </div>
```

Looks like the height of the div is less than the scroll able length